# How to plot three barplots over time on the same axis

Tags: r, time, bar-chart

I have a data frame (df) that contains time (five min intervals) and number of animals that passes by at three different locations. Countings starts and ends at the same time for all three places. They are passing by the three places at different times; first place1, second place2 and third place3 due to their alignment in space.

Today I get:
Number of animals on the y-axis and time on the x-axis (where there are three separate groupings like I want). However, time starts over again for each of the three groupings (thus the x-axis looks like this (start-end, start-end, start-end).

What I want:
A plot with number of counts on the y-axis, and time on the x-axis (from start to end of counting). Thus there will be a "displacement" of number of animals (possible fewer as well) as time goes by.

My code today is:

`barplot(df$nr.animals, names.arg = df$time, xlab="Time", ylab="Number of animals counted")`

How can I get this data into a barplot with time on the x-axis (without the time starting at the beginning again for each new place)?

EDITED:
see picture for some of my dataset:
[time=time, pos has three different values: mmys1, mmys_c1 and mmys_c2, which stands for the three different places, nr.bats.dir1 = number of animals counted in that specific time interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhSrC.png)

see picture of the structure of my dataset:
[time has factor format, nr,bats.dir1 has integer format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oEqI.png)

thus my code is actually like this
`barplot(df$nr.bats.dir1, names.arg = df$time, xlab="Time", ylab="Number of bats counted")`

Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample data using `dput`.

Comment: Most of your text will be better illustrated with data.

Comment: I have tried to add pictures of my dataset, hope this helps. Thanks for taking time to help me!